# Can you send a SMS/text message directly in cURL?

Tags: c++, curl, twilio

I have my C++ program open up the command line for cURL, and I would like cURL to directly send a text message. If it's possible, I'm wondering if anyone can share an example of that.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not asking about email in this question.

Comment: cURL cannot send text messages directly. You need to use a 3rd party SMS/texting gateway that is accessible via HTTP or SMTP, which are two protocols that cURL does support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can [send a text message with Twilio using curl](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages?code-sample=code-send-a-message-with-an-image-url&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json). Here's an example of the call you'd make:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json" \
  --data-urlencode "To=RECEIVING_NUMBER"  \
  --data-urlencode "From=YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER"  \
  --data-urlencode "Body=This is a message sent from curl"  \
  -u YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID:YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN
```

The bits you'd need to fill in are listed in caps.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: For others needing this, you might fix the quotes in the to, from, and body (after equal). For the post command, Windows personally likes double quotes than single, but this probably varies on each machine. Glad it works!

Comment: Do you know if they charge per text, allow URL support (TextBelt had to whitelist for URLs on individual cases), and if it has a programmable two-way chat? Very interested in the user replying yes/no.

Comment: The charges in Twilio are per text, yes. You can send any URL you want. Yes, you can get responses to messages too, there is a guide on [how to receive and reply to messages using Twilio here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-receive-and-reply).

Answer (score 0):

I Use [textbelt](https://textbelt.com/) for this. From their home page you can see their example:

```
curl -X POST https://textbelt.com/text \
   --data-urlencode phone='5557727420' \
   --data-urlencode message='Hello world' \
   -d key=textbelt
```

You can apparently self host the service if running through the public api endpoint is a problem for one reason or another.

Comment: I do like its simplicity, and hoping a script like that can run with Twilio. Textbelt is expensive when ordering texts though. It's $10/250 texts, and that might get very expensive in the long run when the project is released.

Comment: The self hosted option looks to me like it is sending emails directly to the carriers' smtp->sms gateway so that may be the way you want to go.